# EasyMock with Robolectric: EasyMock is not working as expected

Tags: robolectric, android-testing, easymock

This is CustomAdapter (btw: really old code, should be improved some day):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private SortedSet<Integer> mHiddenItems = new TreeSet<>();     

    @Override
    public final int getCount(){
        return mHiddenItems.size();
    }

    ...
}
```

This is my test class CustomAdapterTest (and everything works well here):

```
public class CustomAdapterTest extends TestCase{

    private static final int ITEMS_IN_ADAPTER = 10;
    private CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        super.setUp();

        mCustomAdapter = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(CustomAdapter.class)
            .addMockedMethod("method1")
            .addMockedMethod("method2")
            .createMock();

        expect(mCustomAdapter.method2()).andReturn(ITEMS_IN_ADAPTER).anyTimes();
    }

    public void testOne(){
        EasyMock.replay(mCustomAdapter);
        assertEquals(ITEMS_IN_ADAPTER,mCustomAdapter.getTotalCount());
        .....
    }

    ......

}
```

Attempting to use Robolectric, and after fixing one bug, this is how CustomAdapterTest looks like:

```
@RunWith(RoboelectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class , packageName="my.package.name")
public class CustomAdapterTest{

    private static final int ITEMS_IN_ADAPTER = 10;
    private CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache",RuntimeEnvironment.application.getCacheDir().getPath())

        mCustomAdapter = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(CustomAdapter.class)
            .addMockedMethod("method1")
            .addMockedMethod("method2")
            .createMock();

        expect(mCustomAdapter.method2()).andReturn(ITEMS_IN_ADAPTER).anyTimes();
    }

    public void testOne(){
        EasyMock.replay(mCustomAdapter);
        assertEquals(ITEMS_IN_ADAPTER,mCustomAdapter.getTotalCount());
        .....
    }

    ......

}
```

When I run the CustomAdapterTest#testOne() using Robolectric, I don't know why but `mCustomAdapter.mHiddenItems` is null, causing a NPE when mCustomAdapter.getCount() is called. This is not happening on the first version of CustomAdapterTest. 
 
 1) Why when using RobolectricGradleTestRunner `private SortedSet mHiddenItems = new TreeSet<>();` is not executed ? 
 
 2) How to fix this? I want it to execute `private SortedSet mHiddenItems = new TreeSet<>();` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the exact answer to your question. But I would just rework test and class under test.

I would remove partial mocking and inject items in the constructor or over a setter. Or I would mock items provider again in the constructor.

Comment: This is not a valid solution for my case (maybe for other cases) but thanks, I appreciate your effort on my question.